# Snort rule to detect a three-way handshake

Tags: networking, firewall, rules, traffic, snort

I have been trying to write a rule to detect the establishment of a connection "Three way handshake" using snort IDS:

alert tcp 10.10.10.10 any -> any any (sid:1000; flags:S; msg:"SYN detect";)

Every time i run the snort with this rule it doesn't detect the connection? is there any syntax error !! or should modify anything!

appreciate the help

Comment: Your rule has no problem. Is `sid:1000` only one among rules?

Answer (score 0):

Unless this is the only thing in the configuration, you must remember that rule IDs less than 999,999 are reserved for use by the Snort team/rule feeds.  From the [Snort](http://manual-snort-org.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/node31.html#SECTION00444000000000000000) docs:

> 3.4.4 sid
>
> The sid keyword is used to uniquely identify Snort rules. This information allows output plugins to identify rules easily. This option should be used with the rev keyword. (See section [*])
>
> 2#2100 Reserved for future use
>
> 100-999,999 Rules included with the Snort distribution
>
> 36#361,000,000 Used for local rules

You should rewrite your rule to something like this:

```
 alert tcp 10.10.10.10 any -> any any (sid:100000000; flags:S; msg:"SYN detect";)
```

If your SID matches that of another rule, unpredictable results can occur (like, your rule never seems to fire).